# Error in the pair_trade.R demo in quantsrat

Tags: r, quantstrat

The insightful `pair_trade.R` demo of the wonderful `quanstrat` package (updated minutes ago via SVN) with input parameters: `SD <- 1 ; N <-10` gives the following error:

```
[1] "2009-01-26 00:00:00 DIA -500 @ 76.1735958352934"
Error in `/.default`(TxnFees, abs(TxnQty)) :
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

My `sessionInfo()` is below:

```
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] quantstrat_0.9.1669           foreach_1.4.2
[3] blotter_0.9.1666              PerformanceAnalytics_1.4.3541
[5] FinancialInstrument_1.2.0     quantmod_0.4-3
[7] TTR_0.22-0                    xts_0.9-7
[9] zoo_1.7-11
loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] codetools_0.2-9 grid_3.1.2      iterators_1.0.7 lattice_0.20-29
```

I don't see any explicit mention of `TxnQty` or `TxnFees` in the code, and of course the demo seems to run without error for the original set of parameters `SD <- 2 ; N <- 20`.

Am i missing something or is this a bug?

Comment: It seems to be the same as or related to [bug #5808](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=5808&group_id=316&atid=1269).

Comment: Yes, indeed. The suggested patch gets rid of the error. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the same issue reported in [bug #5808](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=5808&group_id=316&atid=1269), which has been fixed in [r1681 on R-Forge](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/blotter/R/addTxn.R?root=blotter&r1=1681&r2=1680&pathrev=1681).

The issue was that `match.fun(TxnFees)` wasn't being called before transactions that cause the position to cross zero. So there would be an error, if `TxnFees` was a character string representing a function name and a transaction caused the position to cross zero.